# Select the recent record of each person

Tags: mysql

I have the users data in mysql table like below

| Index_No | Message_From | Message_To | Message | Message_Time(Current TimeStamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 123@mail.com | 009@mail.com | hello 009 | 2022-04-24 12:26:13 |
| 02 | 567@mail.com | 008@mail.com | hi 567 | 2022-04-24 12:27:13 |
| 03 | 123@mail.com | 009@mail.com | how are you | 2022-04-24 12:28:13 |
| 04 | 567@mail.com | 008@mail.com | How is the weather | 2022-04-24 12:29:13 |

I need to show the latest record of each user like

| Index_No | Message_From | Message_To | Message | Message_Time(Current TimeStamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | 123@mail.com | 009@mail.com | how are you | 2022-04-24 12:28:13 |
| 04 | 567@mail.com | 008@mail.com | How is the weather | 2022-04-24 12:29:13 |

I am using MySQL does any one know how i will achieve the required result?

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number()  OVER (partition by Message_From order by Message_Time(Current TimeStamp) desc as rank)
then you get the rank=1

Comment: can you please provide me the query for the desired result above

Answer (score -1):

If you are using older versions of mysql then
You need to pick the latest time in your where clause:

```
SELECT
Index_No, Message_From, Message_To, Message, Message_Time 
FROM `table` WHERE Message_Time=(SELECT MAX(Message_Time) FROM `table` t1
 WHERE t1.Message_To=Message_To LIMIT 1) `GROUP BY Message_To `
```

Comment: This query is showing me only the only the Index_No 4 data

Comment: SELECT
Index_No, Message_From, Message_To, Message, Message_Time 
FROM `table` WHERE Message_Time=(SELECT MAX(Message_Time) FROM `table` t1
 WHERE t1.Message_From=Message_From LIMIT 1) `GROUP BY Message_From `

Comment: its showing only Index_No 4 data not the Index_No 3 data i need to show the latest data of all the persons

Comment: Brother just add an alias in your primary query

SELECT Index_No, Message_From, Message_To, Message, Message_Time FROM `table` t WHERE Message_Time=(SELECT MAX(Message_Time) FROM `table` t1 WHERE t1.Message_From=t.Message_From LIMIT 1) GROUP BY Message_From

Comment: still its not working and showing only the Index_No 4 data

Comment: I am not a php developer so I can't tell if your code is written in a way that it can hold list
but I am pretty sure the query I gave you is fine and will give you the desired result set.